# How do you check for whether a checkbox is checked or not checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I thought this would work:

```
if ($(this).attr('checked')) {}
```

but I had to write it this way:

```
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {}
```

Q: Why?

Comment: Why is not a question.  What about this seems strange 2k user?

Comment: Which jquery version are you using?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of jQuery? Because then you'd have to use `.prop` instead of `.attr`

Comment: @Pixelbobby -- I originally put "Because".  The UI complained, so I did a re-write.

Comment: Why not use the simpler and faster `if (this.checked) {` ... ?

Comment: both are working - http://jsfiddle.net/pJgyu/10196/

Comment: @bhu1st - for a good time, try switching that to jQuery 1.6.

Comment: @jamietre jQuery 1.6.1 now should support it http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/12/jquery-1-6-1-released/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having been through this recently, it depends on what version of jQuery you are using. As of 1.6, the functioning of `attr` with native properties (e.g. "checked", "disabled") -- properties being attributes that are supposed to either exist or not - changed, because they could return inconsistent results depending on browser behavior.

The correct way to set or test a property in 1.6 is with the new `prop` function, which returns true or false always. The 2nd method you use is also valid to test.

Answer (score 7):

When you request the attr checked, you are not getting a boolean value:

```
// this would be correct
if($(this).attr('checked') == 'checked')

// jQuery 1.6+
if($(this).prop('checked'))
```

Comment: Like selected I believe there are browsers and cases where this would have failed.  (Thus the change to use prop).

Comment: It is perfectly OK for the value of the attribute to be the boolean constant `true` - specifically it does **not** have to be the string "checked".  In the DOM, the attribute is indeed a simple boolean.

Answer (score 1):

Better yet, just use `this.checked`, which returns either "true" or "false".  No need to use jQuery especially if you already have the DOM node.

Comment: I'm afraid of using any native JavaScript if there is a jQuery alternative because I don't know if it will behave one way in one browser and another way in another browser.  jQuery helps me make sure my code is normalized.

Comment: Understood, I take the same approach most of the time.  However, the `checked` property is 100% cross browser, so in this particular case it will work as expected.